# UI techniques to use for this sample screen. Listview or spinner or others?

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I would like to create application and screen like attached below. My basic question is  what is the techniques that I can use for it ? ListView or Spinner or others.

I'm new on Android and need your advice on this.

![Start of the application menu][1]

```
  MainMenu
```

Category :       personal                       Icon/image of category

Account  :       bank xxxxx                     Icon of bank

Payee    :       .......                        Icon of person

etc...

After clicking one of the 'icon/picture' on the right side, eq."Category :" it is display the second screen, as below :

Entertainment       icon

Personal            icon

car/motor           icon

etc.....

From the second screen, I can choose the item and save it on Sqlite DB. After that, I can view/display it using the same UI, on the 1st screen.

Need your advice / suggestion on what techniques to use on this programming.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For Spinner, try this one. It shows the spinner which have images.
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/